# Would you like to - how to answer correct short answer?

Tags: questions

If somebody asks me:

> Would you like to go to the cinema?

What is the correct short answer?

- Yes, I would.
- Yes, I do.

As I know, short answer should contain the same helper word as the question has.

Comment: "Yes, I would" is the correct choice here. "Yes" would be the shortest reply.

Comment: @aparente001 oh, thank you. Truly say, I was not aware of that SE community.

Comment: @aparente001 flagged it to migrate to EEL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... or "Thanks! Yes, I would."

Comment: How about some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

It's "*(yes, ) I would*", because the question states *Would you*..

It's basically a shorter form of saying "I would like to go to the cinema". In this case the other person is asking you to go to the cinema with him/her.

Stating it as "I do like to go to the cinama" gives it a slightly different meaning, this means that you like to go to cinemas in general.